# update apk without user interaction

Tags: android

I have seen this similar question here but those were asked long time ago , 
My apk is not on Google play and I also not intend to do so.
My first question is that "Is it possible ?"
If yes then how to proceed.
I tried this one

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
  intent.setDataAndType(
           Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/app.apk"),
        "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
     startActivity(intent);
```

But it results in a screen which asks user to install it, I want to skip that page.
If it's not possible then for the sake of knowledge how it happens from Google play or from the ADB command.
Can't we run the adb command from app.

Comment: Unless you have a rooted device, you can't install an APK on a device without the users permission.

Comment: It's a good thing that Android does this and users appreciate it.  Don't try to take it away.  One click is hardly a big deal.

Comment: But how it happens from Google play or from the ADB command.

Answer (score 2):

This is only possible with customised Andoid distribution. To make the long story short, forget that idea. Pressing once ok seems not too much to ask from the user.